# Husky pre-commit hook and echo -e on Linux and Windows

Tags: bash, git, git-bash, husky

I use the [Husky](https://typicode.github.io/husky/) pre-commit hook and I have code like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

...

MISSING="$MISSING\nmissing docs for $path";

...

if [ ! -z "$MISSING" ]; then
    echo -e "$MISSING";
    false
fi
```

The problem is that on Linux `echo -e` makes it render `-e` in the terminal. But without it on Windows (in git bash) it doesn't render newlines.

What should I do to use `echo -e` for both real GNU/Linux and git bash on Windows?

I was investigating the files used by Husky and it has file `.husky/_/husky.sh`

that has this shebang:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
```

but changing it to bash makes no difference.

Comment: Can you use `printf` instead? [ref](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/185805)

Comment: From this, I conclude that `/usr/bin/echo` is executed here, which indeed does not understand `-e`. From this I would follow that in both cases the script is executed by `sh`, ignoring the #! line.  I don't know _husky_, but for rule out this possibility, I would put into the script a `echo versinfo=$BASH_VERSINFO; type echo`. What output do you get from this?

Comment: This is exactly the reason why `echo` shouldn't be used if you require portable scripts. Use `printf` instead which is specified in POSIX and _must_ behave in the defined way

Comment: @user1934428 I have an odd result: `versinfo=\necho is a shell builtin` no version.

Comment: @Guildenstern thanks, `printf` works, forget about this alternative.

Comment: Now it gets interesting. Since $BASH_VERSINFO is empty, we know that you are not running bash, since the variable BASH_VERSINFO is hardcoded in bash and contains the major bash version. OTOH, your shell knows about the `type` command, and we know that it has `echo` as builtin. Further we know that your `echo` does not understand `-e`. I'm not Sherlock Holmes, but an educated guess would be that Husky is running `dash` or `zsh` here, as these two shells would match the observations.

Comment: @user1934428 This OS is Xubuntu I think it has `sh` symlink that points to `dash`. Already had problems with it.

Comment: @jcubic : While I don't understand, why you would use **git-bash** (Windows), when you are actually using Xubuntu, the real question is **how** husky invokes your callback script. If it **sources** your callback script, the callback is executed by - as you found out - dash. If you can confirm this, you better remove the _bash_ tags from your question, as they are irrelevant: No bash involved here.

Comment: @user1934428 Maybe you're not aware but people work in teams. I have Xubuntu but other team members use Windows. I need my script to work on both systems.

Comment: @jcubic : If on the other team dash is used and you use bash, this is going to be tricky. This is certainly a requirement you should state in your question. For instance, does Husky also run in your Windows environment? But here too, you better check how your callback is invoked.

Comment: @user1934428 I'm not sure if you've realized that I solved the issue long ago with printf.

Comment: @jcubic: How about adding this solution as an answer? Note that you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @knittl wrote:

> This is exactly the reason why `echo` shouldn't be used if you require portable scripts. Use `printf` instead which is specified in POSIX and must behave in the defined way

The `printf` command works perfectly but you need to add a newline at the end:

```bash
if [ ! -z "$MISSING" ]; then
    printf "$MISSING\n";
    false
fi
```